# How do I record game wins in swift for iOS to Game Center?

Tags: swift, ios8, game-center

I would like my app to not only report a total score earned back to Game Center, but I would like to report current game '*Won*' **STATUS** and total games *won* in the Leaderboard (as well as report back to the user).

Essentially I want the Game Center Leaderboard to report back total '**WINS**', not just *points*. For the life of me I can not find any code examples that would accomplish this, nor am I finding any information that notes this is even possible.

So I guess this is a two part question: Is this possible *(to report a game is won STATUS)* and, if it is possible, can someone point me in the right direction to look at some example code that would accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe, through my exhaustive research, that this is not possible. Game Center essentially records total points, and I believe they can only go up. It is not possible to simply add/subtract. It just simply accumulates. In addition, Game Center does not seem to offer the ability to record match wins vs. match losses. So there wouldn't be any data for me to query on that either. I'm exploring using a backend data service to create my own leaderboard. This was my conclusion after a week or so of research, but please feel free to correct me; I'm still looking for a solution! Thanks!